# How to use GraphicsMagick to negate the alpha channel of a picture

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I want to invert a image with transparent background, i.e. from

[image], transparent background

to

[image], transparent "We"

In ImageMagick, we can do this by

`convert 1cut.png -channel a -negate +channel 1cut_nega.png`

as mentioned in http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18842

What is the equivalent command in GraphicsMagick?

If I use `$ gm convert -channel opacity -negate +channel example/we.png output/we.png`, I got a white "We" instead of transparent "We"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
gm convert 61I23.png -operator matte negate 1 result.png
```